# My fork fifo c code doesn't work properly

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, fifo

I'm having problems with the following code. I'm doing a lab assignment on using forks (creating processes). Its a simple program thats supposed to read input from keyboard and then read/write it to a fifo and display its contents and bytes written.

When I run it, everything seems fine until i enter some text. The parent print message shows up fine, but the child print message never shows up, until i've entered my second message in which it always says that it wrote 80 bytes even though I know it didn't, and theres a bunch of weird special characters everywhere.

Here is the executable on how the program should be:
Linux: http://www.mediafire.com/?6806v24q6lz7dpc
QNX: http://www.mediafire.com/?a9dhiwmrlx2ktkp

And my code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char FifoName[] = "fifoDan";
    int fd;
    pid_t retval;
    int size_read;
    char buff[80];
    int  size_written;

    mknod(FifoName, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0);

     // Check if its not equal to zero (ie: child process = 0)
     if (retval = fork ()) {

             printf ("Parent: Waiting for writers \n");

             if(fd = open(FifoName, O_RDONLY) == -1) {
                            perror( "Could not read the FIFO" );
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
             }

             printf ("Parent: Received a writer \n");

             do {

                             int strsize;

                             size_read = read(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));

                             printf("Parent: read %d bytes: %s \n", size_read, buff);
                             fflush(stdout);

                            strsize = strlen(buff);

                             //   put a '\0' at the end of the data
                            buff[strsize] = '\0';


                     } while(size_read > 0);


                    close(fd);
                    waitpid(retval, NULL, NULL);

                    if(unlink(FifoName) != -1) {
                            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
                    } else {
                            return EXIT_FAILURE;
                    }


    } else {


      printf ("Child pid %d waiting for readers \n", getpid ());
      fflush(stdout);

       if(fd = open(FifoName, O_WRONLY) == -1) {
                            perror( "Could not read the FIFO" );
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

      printf ("Child: Got a reader, enter some stuff:\n");
      fflush(stdout);

      while(fgets(buff, 80, stdin) != NULL) {

                     int strsize;

                     strsize = strlen(buff);

                     if(strsize < 80) {
                             buff[strsize] = '\0';
                     }

                    size_written = write(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));

                    printf ("Child: wrote %d bytes \n", size_written);
                    fflush(stdout);

             }

             close(fd);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

This line (for example) will not do what you think it does:

```
if(fd = open(FifoName, O_WRONLY) == -1)
```

The equality operator has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the assignment operator, so what you do is actually this:

```
if(fd = (open(FifoName, O_WRONLY) == -1))
```

when you want this:

```
if((fd = open(FifoName, O_WRONLY)) == -1)
```

---

The problem with the buffer reading/writing is because you do write the whole buffer:

```
size_written = write(fd, buff, sizeof(buff));
```

Change to write only the actual string using `strsize` instead.

Comment: +1. It's been my experience in writing C for 27 years now that, while it's legal to write assignments inside if statements, it's also a wonderful way to create bugs. An extra line of code for a simple assignment won't slow down the compile much. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It fixed the problem I'm having. But now it says that both the parent and the child have read/written 80 bytes every single time I enter something, instead of counting the number of bytes I enter from my keyboard. Maybe I'm passing in the wrong value?

Comment: @user1930558 That's because you _write_ 80 bytes. You write the whole buffer since you use `sizeof(buff)` in the `write` call.

Comment: Hmm, but then what should I be writing? Like how would I know the size of the message? I'm not sure if stdin can be counted

Comment: @user1930558 See my updated answer. you already _have_ the length of the string in `strsize` (by the way, do don't need to terminate the string, `fgets` does it for you, otherwise `strlen` wouldn't work).